# Xamarin.Android Selector xml for Button Blank

Tags: android, xml, xamarin.android

I've been following a guide in which i make a custom button selector and then set it as the background property for the button in my main.axml file.

However, in both the Designer and when the app runs, the button renders completely white, and it should actually be blue.

Here is the xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="https://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_pressed="false">
    <layer-list>
      <item android:right="5dp" android:top="5dp">
        <shape>
          <corners android:radius="2dp"/>
          <solid android:color="#D6D6D6"/>
        </shape>
      </item>
      <item android:bottom="2dp" android:left="2dp">
        <shape>
          <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="#4A6EA9" android:startColor="#4A6EA9"/>
          <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#BABABA"/>
          <corners android:radius="4dp"/>
          <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp"/>
        </shape>
      </item>
    </layer-list>
  </item>
  <item android:state_pressed="true"> 
    <layer-list>
      <item android:right="5dp" android:top="5dp">
        <shape>
          <corners android:radius="2dp"/>
          <solid android:color="#D6D6D6"/>
        </shape>
      </item>
      <item android:bottom="2dp" android:left="2dp">
        <shape>
          <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="#7C97C1" android:startColor="#4A6EA9"/>
          <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#BABABA"/>
          <corners android:raduis="4dp"/>
          <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp"/>
        </shape>
      </item>
    </layer-list>  
  </item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `https` with `http`

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
```